# Items are looping all items in Repeater's ItemDataBound event

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a normal `Repeater` Control in my aspx page

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt1_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chks" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.Name").ToString()%>'></asp:TextBox><asp:Label ID="lblValue" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.Id").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

On the button click I'm binding data to the `Repeater` as

```
rpt1.DataSource = GetData();
rpt1.DataBind();
```

After binding the `ItemDataBound` event is called. In that I'm looping through the repeater items for some manipulations

```
protected void rpt1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rpt1.Items)
    {
        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
             string val = ((Label)item.FindControl("lblValue")).Text;
            // Some Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the loop is getting started from first every time.

For Ex if my data is as 1 2 3 so on.....

It is iterarting as

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
```

How can I make it as

```
1
2
3
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: @TimSchmelter is correct you don't to loop inside an `Repeater ItemDataBound` as it will automatically iterate **n** number of items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ItemDataBound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) is already called for every item in the repeater, so you don't need a loop there.

```
protected void rpt1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
         string val = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblValue")).Text;
        // Some Stuff
    }
}
```

Side-Note: that applies to all [Data-Bound Web Server Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214.aspx).